# What value should `std::stringstream::fail()` return after reading then writing? (gcc vs clang)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, iostream, sstream

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "12345";
    unsigned short s;
    ss >> s;
    ss << "foo";

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << "\nss.eof()  = " << ss.eof()
              << "\nss.good() = " << ss.good()
              << "\nss.bad()  = " << ss.bad()
              << "\nss.fail() = " << ss.fail()
              << "\nss.str()  = " << ss.str();
}
```

---

clang++ trunk prints the following result:

> ```
> ss.eof()  = true
> ss.good() = false
> ss.bad()  = false
> ss.fail() = false
> ss.str()  = 12345
> ```

[**on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6WLJhkpnmMbM49fm)

---

g++ trunk prints the following result:

> ```
> ss.eof()  = true
> ss.good() = false
> ss.bad()  = false
> ss.fail() = true
> ss.str()  = 12345
> ```

[**on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RcAGQjV55MnG7jPq)

---

As you can see, the value of `ss.fail()` is different between the two compilers. What does the Standard say regarding the behavior of `std::stringstream` in this case? Is it implementation-defined to set `failbit`/`badbit` when writing to a stream that has already been consumed?

Comment: This sounds like a library issue rather than a compiler issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gcc is correct. `std::stringstream` inherits from `std::basic_ostream`, and according to the behavior of [`operator<<(std::basic_ostream)`](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.formatted#ostream.inserters.character-4) (which is invoked from `ss << "foo";`),

> Effects: Behaves like a formatted inserter (as described in [ostream.formatted.reqmts]) of out.

And from [§30.7.5.2.1/1 Common requirements [ostream.formatted.reqmts]](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.formatted.reqmts#1):

(emphasis mine)

> Each formatted output function begins execution by constructing an object of class sentry. If this object returns true when converted to a value of type bool, the function endeavors to generate the requested output. **If the generation fails, then the formatted output function does setstate(ios_­base​::​failbit)**, which might throw an exception.

And [§30.7.5.1.3 Class basic_­ostream​::​sentry [ostream::sentry]](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream::sentry):

> If os.good() is nonzero, prepares for formatted or unformatted output.
>   If os.tie() is not a null pointer, calls os.tie()->flush().
>
> If, after any preparation is completed, os.good() is true, ok_­ ==
>   true otherwise, ok_­ == false. During preparation, the constructor may
>   call setstate(failbit) (which may throw ios_­base​::​​failure
>   ([iostate.flags]))

And [§30.5.5.4 basic_­ios flags functions [iostate.flags]](http://eel.is/c++draft/iostate.flags):

> iostate rdstate() const;
>   Returns: The error state of the stream buffer.
>
> bool good() const;
>   Returns: rdstate() == 0
>
> bool eof() const;
>   Returns: true if eofbit is set in rdstate().

`eofbit` has been set in this case, then `std::basic_ios::good` returns nonzero and causes writing failed (as the result showed), then `failbit` should be set.

Comment: Looks like std::basic_ostream::sentry is responsible for setting the failbit if eof occurs.

Comment: @BoPersson The requirements are different for input and output functions. According to the standard, "Formatted output functions" should be responsible for setting the `failbit`.

Comment: Yes, I quoted different sections from the different documents. A mixup. However, the text quoted here doesn't say explicitly what happens when the first if-condition is false, and the stream doesn't even attempt to generate anything. [ostream::sentry] says, a bit vague, "During preparation, the constructor may call setstate(failbit)".